# How to downgrade firebase versions

Tags: reactjs, firebase, npm, version

I am following a tutorial with React.js and Firebase and since the tutorial is from 2020 I believe he is  using firebase version 8 or 9. I have never used firebase before and was following this tutorial step by step to try to gain some knowledge on it. I realized after getting a bunch of errors that I am using firebase 10.1.0 and a lot of things syntax has changed between the versions. I would like to just downgrade to version 8 so I can still follow along the tutorial the same but am having a lot of issues doing so.

so far I have tried these commands:

```
npm i -S firebase@9
npm i -S firebase@9.6.2

npm uninstall firebase
npm install --save firebase@8.2.1
```

After running all of these separately and checking the version (with firebase --version) in between no matter what it still says I am running version 10.1.0

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong or what I can do differently to downgrade this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the v8 syntax with the latest SDK versions, you can import the `compat` paths as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade#update_imports_to_v9_compat). That should make most existing tutorials out there work as is.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is change the version to 8 with the downgrade command :
npm i firebase@8.8.0

or
version upper until 9.4

[import_firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6dw7.png)

[CLI_firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHA09.png)